# opacity map on bitmap android

Tags: android, opacity

I have two bitmaps, one wallpaper image and another, a black and white image that will contain   the alpha information. I want to apply that alpha information to the wallpaper image.

Now I know that I can change opacity like this:

```
img.setOpacity(50);
```

But this sets the alpha of the whole bitmap, which is not what I want. I want an advanced way to set alpha of image based on a black and white source.

Answer (score 0):

You want [Bitmap.setPixel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setPixel%28int,%20int,%20int%29). For example, assuming your Bitmaps are the same size:

```
Bitmap a,b;//initialized - a is the b&w image, b is the normal image

for (int x = 0; x < a.width(); x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < a.height(); y++)
    {
        int color = b.getPixel(x, y);
        int red = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
        int green = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
        int blue = (color >> 0) & 0xFF;
        if (a.getPixel(x, y) == Color.WHITE)
            b.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(0.5, red, green, blue));//alpha = 0.5
        else
            b.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(1, red, green, blue));//alpha = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: tried, got an error:java.lang.IllegalStateException
07-19 20:41:30.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8210):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.setPixel(Bitmap.java:1074).....For the record, this is how I am supposed to draw,right? 
                 c.drawBitmap(b, 0, 0, p);

Comment: Have you considered just using an _ImageView_?

Comment: i am using it in a live wallpaper